# Bottom align a textview with an ImageView in a GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

So far this is the result of my layout

[image: Layout]

I am trying to put the textview at the bottom of my ImageView (not below it). The textview should BottomAlign with the ImageView.

The image of my ImageView is a square. If the content of the textview turns out to be longer that the width of my ImageView, the content should continues to the next line.

At the moment i don't care if the content of the ImageView does not scaled proportionally (i.e. gets stretched, etc).

This is the XML that i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconItem"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textItem"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/shout_ic"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:text="Motorcycles"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#8888"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i achieve the result i want?

EDIT 1:

I think i am making a progress... (but not exactly like what i have in mind

[image: image is still too small]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbqoo_launcher_ic"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iconItem"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:text="Motorcycles"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#8888"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want your TextView to have a fixed width, why are you using fill_parent? Try setting its width to 80dp, like the ImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your parent layout to `FrameLayout` with orientation `vertical` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconItem"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#8888"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Motorcycles"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="11sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps i get this wrong. What i meant is to have the textView on top of the ImageView only the bottom of the text view is align with the bottom of the imageview. Your solution appears to place the textview below the image view.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textItem"` from your imageview and try adding line `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iconItem"`in your `TextView`

set width of `ImageView` to width of your row layout

Answer (score 1):

```
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUY4o.png Check the sample image...
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/album_item"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/cover"
       android:layout_width="148dp"
       android:layout_height="148dp"
       android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cover"
     android:background="#70000000"
     android:padding="6dp" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconItem"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textItem"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/shout_ic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8888"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Motorcycles"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="11sp" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iconItem"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```